# My HR manager told me to wear blur or black shirt for orientation. Should I wear long sleeve or short sleeve?

Tags: new-job, dress-code

I was offered a job in an airport near my home. In the dress code sheet that she gave me, it said that I would have to wear blue or black shirt and blue or black work pants. I have the pants but J need to know if it has to be long sleeved or short sleeved.

Comment: Call him and ask. There is no way for us to know.

Comment: I did send an email but it's been 2 days. And I'm not sure if I should even go with work shirts. Just a formal blue/black shirt is coming into my mind..

Comment: Long sleeves would be my choice, go formal if you don't know the protocol is always best, particularly if you're in a public facing position, even more so if you have a tattoo on your forearm as many people do.

Answer (score 2):

If they didn't say, it probably doesn't matter, especially at a time when the weather is highly variable. If they don't answer the question, I wouldn't worry about it... but longsleeve is always safer, and you can always roll up the sleeves.